# How to replace text in Jms Payment Paypal Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I have the paypal bundle working in JMS Core Payment ***(symfony2)***.
However, in the checkout I have the text:

**Data paypal express checkout**

I have done a site wide search for this and can not find this text anywhere.
No answers on Google too!

Anyone have an idea how to translate this or even delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using this code:

```
{{ form_row(form.data_paypal_express_checkout, {'label': ' ', 'label_attr': {'class': 'hide'}}) }}
```

and add own messages using this translation key:

```
form.label.paypal_express_checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use form theming. As described [here](http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/accepting_payments.html#changing-how-the-form-looks), add a theme file:

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Orders/theme.html.twig #}

{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

and reference it from the template where the form is rendered:

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Orders/show.html.twig #}

{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:Orders:theme.html.twig' %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Pay € {{ order.amount }}" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Then, add the *"jms_choose_payment_method_data_paypal_express_checkout"* label field with no content in the theme file:

```
{% block _jms_choose_payment_method_data_paypal_express_checkout_label %}
{% endblock %}
```

And you're done.